# ASP.NET Web Forms - error message with parameter like in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET MVC I can do something like that (parameter is set as DisplayName):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please insert a valid {0}") ]
[DisplayName("User name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

So error message "*Please insert a valid {0}*" is translated to "*Please insert a valid User name*". Can I do something like that in ErrorMessage in ASP.NET Web Forms in below code??

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" Text="E-mail" runat="server" Width="300px" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredEmailValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field {0} is required." ControlToValidate="Email" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

So error message "`Field {0} is required`" should be translated to "`Field E-mail is required`".

Answer (score 3):

The `RequiredFieldValidator` is an ASP.NET validation control that validates a single field (`ControlToValidate` property). That means the message you define for one of these validators should be just the specific message for the field being validated. 
In this case:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" Text="E-mail" runat="server" Width="300px" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredEmailValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field E-mail is required." ControlToValidate="Email" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" Text="User Name" runat="server" Width="300px" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredEmailValidatorUN" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field User Name is required." ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Following this logic, you would have one `RequiredFieldValidator` instance for each field you need to validate, and the message would be defined for each validation separately.

It is also possible to set this message via javascript as each `RequiredFieldValidator` is rendered on the page and therefore can be manipulated. The same is valid for changing it via C# on code-behind.

Comment: ^ This is a good and fast way to do this. If you don't do it this way, you would have to use some C# code behind to do you check to see if a field is the fields are left empty, then output your error message out in an asp:label or HTML element.

Comment: So if I change TextBox Text from "User Name" to "Login" I will have to change also ErrorMessage from "Field User Name is required." to "Field Login is required." - in ASP.NET MVC it is more comfortable :)

Comment: @michael yes, you would have to change the message also. You actually could do this dynamically but it would require a little bit more C# code on your code-behind as it is not a built in functionality.